Solvability of the oblique derivative boundary value problem
Let $\Omega$ be a bounded $C^{2,\alpha}$ domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that satisfies an interior sphere condition at each point of $\partial \Omega$, i.e., for each $x_0\in \partial \Omega$, there exists a ball $B\subset \Omega$ such that $x_0 \in \partial B$. Consider the following oblique derivative boundary value problem
\begin{align*}
      Lu&=f\quad\rm in\,\, \Omega\\
       \langle\beta, Du\rangle &=\phi\quad \rm on \,\, \partial \Omega,
\end{align*}
where $L$ is uniformly elliptic with $C^{0,\alpha}$ coefficients and $c\equiv 0$, $\beta \in C^{1,\alpha}(\partial \Omega)$, $\langle \beta,\nu\rangle>0$ on $\partial \Omega$ ($\nu$ is the outer normal vector field at $\partial \Omega$), $f \in C^{1,\alpha}(\overline \Omega)$, and  $\phi \in C^{1,\alpha}(\partial\Omega)$.  Under what conditions, does the following problem admit a solution in  $C^{2,\alpha}(\overline \Omega)$, which is unique up to an additive constant?
When $L = \Delta$ and $\beta = \nu$, then a necessary condition for the existence of the solution is
$$
\int_\Omega f = \int_{\partial \Omega} \phi.
$$
The above condition, known as the compatibility condition, is also sufficient.
